# Web Speech API has "Network Error"

Tags: google-chrome, webspeech-api

I'm using Web Speech API to recognize user voice. Recently I meet the Error that I cannot recognize anything. Check the console on Chrome I get SpeechRecognitionError

```
currentTarget: SpeechRecognition
defaultPrevented: false
error: "network"
type: "error"
```

I have working network. And it just happen to my chrome, my coworker chrome is working fine.
I suspect this bug is because of chrome itself, is there any work around for it?

Comment: Were you able to solved this problem by any chance? I am having a similar issue.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot solve it yet.